# Using Fbo to render the root widget in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, fbo

I have a `Popup` for which I want to make its background translucent. I get the picture for bluring by rendering `app.root` to an `Fbo`, however when I restore the `app.root` widget from the `Fbo`, the widget is not being rendered every frame, but only when an `Animation` on any widget is running or the window is being dragged. The full file is here: https://github.com/XtremeWare/XtremeUpdater/blob/master/src/main.py#L493

**snippet:**

```
def render_background(*args):
    fbo = Fbo(size=app.root.size, with_stencilbuffer=True)

    with fbo:
        Scale(1, -1, 1)
        Translate(-app.root.x, -app.root.y - app.root.height, 0)

    fbo.add(app.root.canvas)
    fbo.draw()
    tex = fbo.texture
    fbo.remove(app.root.canvas)
    tex.flip_vertical()

    img = Image.frombytes('RGBA', tex.size, tex.pixels)
    img = img.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(50))

    tex = Texture.create(size=img.size)
    tex.blit_buffer(
        pbuffer=img.tobytes(), size=img.size, colorfmt='rgba')
    tex.flip_vertical()
    self.canvas.before.get_group('blur')[0].texture = tex

Clock.schedule_once(render_background)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. The following line needs to be at the **end**.

```
Window.canvas.insert(0, app.root.canvas)
```